# pymysql SELECT query with field of table that the user gives as input

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, pymysql

i wondering if it's possible to make a query with select with the user give the field of table and the value that want. For example:

```
field=input("Field: ")
value=input("Value: ")
cursorobject.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE {}=\'{}\'')
result=cursorobject.fetchall()
for x in result:
     print(x)
```

and if it's not possible , there is any way to do it?

PS: this one not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can construct the text of your query as you want using variables. E.g.

```
query = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE {}=\'{}\''
print(query.format(field,value))
```

But, have in mind that you should validate very well the contents of the variables, before executing the query, to avoid [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). For example the contents of the variables should not contain quotes.

E.g. the below code, with the specific values of the variables, will return the full list of users:

```
field='name'
value='name\' or \'1\'=\'1'
query = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE {}=\'{}\''
print(query.format(field,value))
```

The produced query would be:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='name' or '1'='1'
```

Following your edit, you should replace your 3rd line with:

```
cursorobject.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE {}=\'{}\''.format(field,value))
```

And for making the best to avoid sql injections, you should use the built-in query parameterization features of your framework - pymysql:

```
cursorobject.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE {}=%s'.format(field),(value))
```

Comment: it gives me an error ""You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '}='{}'' at line 1")" , for ur 2nd point the only way to avoid SQL injection is the validation of contents? look the edited code.

Comment: Did you execute the `query.format(field,value)` before executing the query? These curly brackets should have been replaced by the values, and not sent to MySql.

Comment: the `query.format(field,value)` just print SELECT id FROM user where input1=input2 i mean its right the syntax there but how can i send it in sql

Comment: @laland see the last line of my answer - I just edited.

Comment: it works thank you , so the only way to avoid sql injection there is to care about inputs contents?

Comment: **WARNING**: Use parameterization especially with user input. Else [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)!

Comment: @laland as @Parfait warns, using query parameterization for the custom values is the best way to avoid sql injections. For the `field` part, on the other hand, it is still dangerous, and yes, you should validate the input given by the user not to contain special characters (single quotes, double quotes, commas, semicolon, spaces etc). In general, you should eliminate characters that are not allowed in a column name.

Answer (score 1):

Simply format the query for *field* and pass *value* as a parameter in second argument of [`cursor.execute`](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html) which must receive an iterable (i.e., tuple/list):

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE {} = %s'

# EXECUTE QUERY
cursorobject.execute(sql.format(field), (value,))

result = cursorobject.fetchall()
```